# How can I check a DB file from a bash script?

Tags: bash, sqlite

I need to create a bash script that checks the Epiphany's browser history and if the last URL visited is 192.168.8.1 then redirect to another URL.
So, the Epiphany's browser history is shown in the following file:

```
/home/pi/.config/ephy-history.db
```

It's a database file.

How can I check the ephy-history.db file from a bash script?

This should the query to check the last URL (title) visited:

```
select title from urls where last_visit_time in (select max(last_visit_time) from urls);
```

Comment: Is it a mysql database?

Comment: Not sure what kind of db is. I think I can use this on the bash script: sqlite3 /home/pi/.config/ephy-history.db select title from urls where last_visit_time in (select max(last_visit_time) from urls);

Comment: You are going to need to use the sqlite3 program inside your script to check  for what you want. This is not really related to Raspberry Pi though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
S1="Tittle of the web I want to show"
S2=$(sudo sqlite3 "/home/pi/.config/ephy-history.db" "select title from urls where last_visit_time in (select max(last_visit_time) from urls);")

if [ "$S1" = "$S2" ]; then
        echo "do nothing"
else
        echo "close the last tab opened in the browser"
        xte "keydown Control_L" "keydown w" "keyup Control_L" "keyup w" -x:0
fi
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.